# MVC 4 Pass value from Javascript to Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view, I have a javascript function to handle a select event on a pie chart.  The function is shown below:

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = visualization.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
        var val = data.getFormattedValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        location.href = '/Tickets';
    }
}
```

Currently I am on the *Home* Controller in the *Groups* View.  I want to navigate to the *Index* View of the *Tickets* Controller while passing the selected value from the javascript variable "val".  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: see this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878418/how-to-pass-values-to-controller-from-javascript-code-in-mvc][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878418/how-to-pass-values-to-controller-from-javascript-code-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location.href = '/Tickets?val=' + val;
```

Comment: Not sure if I like using the query string, but this definitely works while everything else I tried fails.

Answer (score 2):

Are you intending to manually navigate the user?

If you're looking for a redirect JavaScript way, then you would do something as simple as...

```
location.href = '/Tickets?value=' + val;
```

Now this may not work for everything.  For example, if location.href already contains a '?', and you need to maintain that context, then you need to use '&'.  Maybe your app lives in a Virtual Directory.

You might do something like...

```
var newUrl = location.href;
if (newUrl.indexOf('?') > -1)
  newUrl += '&';
else
  newUrl += '?';

newUrl += val;
```

This allows you maintain any existing context as well.

If you expect the ticket to already be defined, you might need to remove that from the query string, if it already exists.

In that case then you might want to do something like...

```
var params = location.search.substring(1).split('&'),
    paramToRemove, indexOfValue,
    hasSearch = false,
    param;
for (var i = 0, len = i; i < len; i++)
{
  param = params[i];
  indexOfValue = param.indexOf('value');
  hasSearch = param.indexOf('?') === 0;
  if (indexOfValue  === 0 || (indexOfValue === 1 && hasSearch ))
  {
    paramToRemove = params[i];
    break;
  }
}

var newUrl = location.href;
// Remove old value
if (paramToRemove) newUrl = newUrl.replace(paramToRemove, hasSearch ? '?' : '');

// Add proper search char
if (newUrl.indexOf('?') > -1)
  newUrl += '&';
else
  newUrl += '?';
// Add new value
newUrl += val;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//On page load the server will generate the URL for you.
var ticketURL = '@Url.Action("Index", "Tickets")';
//Append the value to the URL
ticketURL = ticketURL + '?val=' + val;
//Do your stuff!
```

Comment: This errors out with the message "The name 'val' does not exist in the current context".  I tried doing this as well: `location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Tickets", new { value = @:val })';` but that didn't work either with the error saying the parenthesis don't match up.

Comment: @ruhler - Sorry, I was running low on caffeine.  I updated my post with the correct code.  You may need to restructure it depending on what you need to do, but, the must-have code is there.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are calling Controller methods from javascript. You should make an POST ajax call to Ticket Controller and passing Action method name also.

Your code would be like this:

**return $.post('/Ticket(ControllerName)/Index(method name)/',parameters here);**

Inside API Controller, Index method will accept the same param which we are passing from our javascript.

**ActionResult Index(parameter){...}**

Comment: This seems to return the view within my current view, which is not what I want to do (unless I am doing it wrong?).  I want to actually navigate to the Tickets view.